# Inserir dois comandos (INSERT e UPDATE) na mesma instrução no SQLite, via Linguagem R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

Olá, pessoal

Estou com um problema em saber como inserir dois comandos (INSERT e UPDATE) na mesma instrução no SQLite, via Linguagem R.

Não sei se isso seja impossível por deficiência do SQLite ou do pacote DBI do R.

Segue imagem, com exemplo reprodutível, sobre o que estou tentando fazer:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "cars_a", head(cars, 3))

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "cars_b", head(cars, 3))

DBI::dbExecute(con, 
    "INSERT INTO cars_a
     VALUES (10, 10 );

     UPDATE cars_b
     SET dist = 400
     WHERE speed = 7;"

DBI::dbReadTable(con, "cars_a")

DBI::dbReadTable(con, "cars_b")
```

OBS: Embora as tabelas estejam nomeadas como "cars_a" e "cars_b" interpretem que elas estejam relacionadas. No meu caso, como estou trabalhando com um Web Scraping, o INSERT tem o propósito de agregar dados na tabela com os dados raspados, e o UPDATE faz a atualização na tabela de requisição.

Depois de tentar várias formas, só consegui executar a primeira instrução do SQL. Conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: OBS: Preciso ter os dois comandos na mesma instrução do SQL para garantir que o INSERT e o UPDATE serão feitos. A solução que estou adotando hoje é colocar os comandos em instruções separadas, mas não é o ideia no que toca á performance e sobre o viés da segurança da informação.

Comment: George, edite a pergunta, adicione essa observação. Além disso, adicione seu código, não imagem, assim quem quiser simular, testar, facilita, e melhor organizado! ✌️

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta com copy/paste das instruções, não como imagens. Com o código podemos copiar para uma sessão do R e testar, com imagens não podemos, temos que introduzir tudo outra vez via teclado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colocar as duas instruções para ser executada na mesma `query` provavelmente é possível, entretanto isso não irá garantir que as duas operações serão realizadas. Pois mesmo que seja enviada na mesma `query`, ele irá executar apenas um comando por vez.

**Como garantir que duas operações sejam realizadas no banco?**

Para isso você pode usar a `Transaction` (em português, transação) que é utilizado para garantir a integridade e a confiabilidade dos dados.

**Como o `transaction` funciona?**

A transação possui três comandos:

`BEGIN`: Inicia a transação.

`COMIT`: Confirma as operações realizadas no banco.

`ROLLBACK`: Desfaz as operações realizadas.

**Como usar?**

Veja um exemplo, retirado deste [site](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/DBI/html/transactions.html)

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbBegin(con) # inicia a transação
withdrawal <- 5000

#realiza duas operações de update
dbExecute(con, "UPDATE cash SET amount = amount + ?", list(withdrawal)) 
dbExecute(con, "UPDATE account SET amount = amount - ?", list(withdrawal))

# realiza uma verificação
if (dbReadTable(con, "account")$amount >= 0) {
  dbCommit(con)
} else {
  dbRollback(con)
}
```

Na verificação realizada, caso passe na sua condição ele irá realizar `dbCommit(con)` confirmado os dois `UPDATE` que ele havia feito anteriormente, caso a condição de validação seja falsa, ele irá realizar um `dbRollback(con)` desfazendo as alterações do `UPDATE`.

Você pode ler mais sobre SQLite com Transação [aqui](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/) e [aqui](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/DBI/html/transactions.html).