# Como assegurar que todas as informações foram gravadas no banco?

Tags: c#, mysql

Venho percebendo que estou com problemas ao gravar informações no banco pois:

-Eu estou rodando um bloco de um método que grava dados no banco:

```
//codigo aqui
MySQLCallDB.InsertData("PEDIDOS", columns, values); //gravando informações
//codigo quebra por alguma Exception aqui ou seja, terei um Pedido sem Detalhes
MySQLCallDB.InsertData("PEDIDOS_DETALHES", columns, values); //gravando informações
//Restante do código
```

O método `InsertData` é de uma classe estática que gerencia as consultas na minha aplicação(`MySQLCallDB`) e o código e o modo como eu chamo o MYSQL em `InsertData` é:

```
public static string InsertData(string table, List < string > columns, List < string > values) {
    string Query = "QUERY";
    Query += "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID;";
    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("", conexao);
    comm.CommandText = Query;
    try {
        conexao.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        return reader.GetString("ID");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.WriteLine(Query);
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        return "Error";
    } 
    finally {
      conexao.Close(); //Fechando a conexão}}
    }
}
```

A pergunta é: em casos na qual acontece uma Exception que quebra todo o processo (como descrito nos comentários do código), o que eu devo fazer para não ter informações sem lógica dentro do banco?

Comment: Use dentro do try o BeginTransaction - Commit e no catch RollBack. Vê esse exemplo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_BeginTransaction.htm

Comment: Acredito que a resposta dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318015/inserir-dois-comandos-insert-e-update-na-mesma-instru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-sqlite-via-lingua/318142#318142) pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: É isso. Você tem de fazer os inserts e updates dentro de uma transação de acordo com o modelo ACID. https://www.diegomacedo.com.br/tag/atomicidade/

Answer (score 1):

Terá que trabalhar com transações, de forma a que caso não aconteça nada, se faça `Commit` às alterações e tudo seja gravado de forma coerente na base de dados, e em caso contrário se faça `Rollback` para que nada seja gravado para não provocar inconsistências.

```
// aqui pressupomos que a variável "conexao" está acessível
void GravaDadosBD()
{
    MySqlTransaction myTrans = null;

    try
    {
        conexao.Open();
        myTrans = conexao.BeginTransaction();

        MySQLCallDB.InsertData("PEDIDOS", columns, values);
        MySQLCallDB.InsertData("PEDIDOS_DETALHES", columns, values);

        // correu tudo bem, sem erros, fazer Commit()
        myTrans.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        myTrans?.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        // fechar a conexão apenas depois de executar tudo
        conexao?.Close();
    }
}

public static string InsertData(string table, List <string> columns, List <string> values) 
{
    string Query = "QUERY SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID;";
    string strResult = "Error";
    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, conexao);

    try 
    {
        MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();
        strResult = reader.GetString("ID");

        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Query);
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }

    return strResult;
}
```

Comment: entendi, deixa eu te perguntar, se eu tiver várias chamadas que criam outras conexões, esse processo não vai funcionar, tem que ocorrer tudo em uma só conexão, procede?

Comment: Não, pode ser utilizado em qualquer conexão. No exemplo acima coloquei tudo na mesma, mas poderia ser em duas separadas (uma para cada evocação do método `InsertData`).

Comment: João, mas digamos que eu queria usar o rollback, se eu aplicar na conexão1 ele vai aplicar na conexão2? é isso que eu gostaria de saber

Comment: Não, o `Rollback()` apenas diz respeito à transação associada a uma conexão apenas.

Comment: o que significa o `?` depois de `transaction` em `mysql.transaction?.Rollback();`

Comment: O "?" é utilizado para o nulo condicional, ou seja, ele só executa o `Commit()` e o `Rollback()` caso o objeto `myTrans` não seja nulo. Pode ler sobre isso aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: Valeu ! eu vou aplicar as mudanças no meu código, se resolver eu marco como a correta. Mas acredito que realmente seja a correta ;)